# Total Sales per month having only Start and End date of a contract SQL, PYTHON, R

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total sales per month. My data has columns called "Account Number","SALE", "Contract Start Date" and "Contract End Date". I don't know how the syntax for the revenue in between both dates would be. Help would be greatly appreciated!

| Account Number | SALE | Contract Start Date | Contract End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 253050 | 134.00 | 01-04-2019 | 01-04-2026 |
| 222015 | 142.00 | 01-07-2017 | 01-07-2022 |
| 253010 | 134.00 | 01-02-2018 | 01-02-2024 |
| 251045 | 110.00 | 01-05-2015 | 01-07-2028 |
| 345082 | 100.00 | 01-04-2012 | 01-04-2030 |
| 208321 | 110.00 | 01-02-2018 | 01-07-2027 |
| 780193 | 99.00 | 01-04-2015 | 01-04-2026 |
| 222015 | 142.00 | 01-07-2017 | 01-07-2022 |

Edit

I am trying to get the total sales per month.

| Date | SALE |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1434.00 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1426.00 |
| 03-01-2022 | 1344.00 |
| 04-01-2022 | 1105.00 |
| 05-01-2022 | 1010.00 |
| 06-01-2022 | 1100.00 |
| 07-01-2022 | 919.00 |
| 08-01-2022 | 1420.00 |

Comment: Choose one language please. Also, show us what you have tried so far. An example of your expected output will also help greatly to illustrate what you are asking for.

Comment: The question is confusing. You want monthly sales that occurred between the start and end dates of a contract? All the contracts end and start on the same month, do you want sum of sales on each year of contracts that started? Can you clarify what data you expect?

Comment: hello @guasi My data is formatted with the month in the second position of the date. I am looking to sum all the values of the sale between the start date and end date. I want to create a projection with the monthly sales.

Comment: Please post your expected output